# Prove upper type bound for generic types

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have a type class which I'd like to use to store a type of an object:

```
trait RetainType {
  type A
}

object RetainType {
  def apply[A0](): RetainType = new RetainType{
    type A = A0
  }
}
```

Given the following class:

```
trait Annotation
class Entity extends Annotation
```

I would like the compiler to prove that `RetainType.A` extends `Annotation`:

```
def hasAnnotation[A <: Annotation] = Unit
```

But using `RetainType` the compiler does not seem to resolve this:

```
val retainType = RetainType[Entity]
hasAnnotation[RetainType.A] //throws an error: type arguments [retainType.A] do not conform to method hasAnnotation's type parameter bounds [A <: Annotation]
```

It works ok if the type is specified:

```
hasAnnotation[Entity] //works fine
```

Anyway the compiler can prove this relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You messed up the signature of `RetainType.apply`:

```
def apply[A0](): RetainType
```

The return type does not mention `A0`, so it is "forgotten". That is, in

```
val x = RetainType[Int]
```

`x.A` is completely abstract; the compiler cannot prove that `x.A = Int` because `apply`'s signature erased that information. Use a refinement type:

```
object RetainType {
  def apply[A0](): RetainType { type A = A0 } = new RetainType { override type A = A0 }
}
```

You may want to use the `Aux` pattern to make this nicer to work with:

```
object RetainType {
  type Aux[A0] = RetainType { type A = A0 }
  def apply[A0](): RetainType.Aux[A0] = new RetainType { override type A = A0 }
}
```